# Redshift: Query all tables with a common column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view in Redshift to enable us to see the latest data in each table.
We have datasets that update a various schedules and every table has a column "updated" that contains a datestamp of the rows last update.

What I want to achive is a view at the bottom (from these two example tables):

```
other.bigtable
+-----+--------+------------------+
| id  |  stat  |     updated      |
+-----+--------+------------------+
| A2  | rgerhg | 03/05/2020 05:00 |
| F5  | bdfb   | 03/05/2020 05:00 |
| GF5 | bb     | 03/05/2020 05:00 |
+-----+--------+------------------+
```

```
default.test
+----+------+------------------+
| id | name |     updated      |
+----+------+------------------+
|  1 | A    | 02/02/2008 00:00 |
|  2 | B    | 02/02/2008 00:00 |
|  3 | C    | 02/02/2008 00:00 |
|  4 | F    | 02/02/2008 00:00 |
|  5 | T    | 02/02/2010 00:00 |
+----+------+------------------+
```

```
default.view_updates
+---------+------------+------------------+
| schema  | table_name |    max_update    |
+---------+------------+------------------+
| default | test       | 02/02/2010 00:00 |
| other   | big_table  | 03/05/2020 05:00 |
+---------+------------+------------------+
```

So far I am as far as getting tables and schemas but have no idea where to start on the dates. Redshift seems a bit more limited.

EDIT:

Utilising some code stolen from the web I was hoping to use this to then create the table for the extra column:

```
    select t.table_schema,
        t.table_name
    from information_schema.tables t
    inner join information_schema.columns c 
        on c.table_name = t.table_name 
        and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
    where c.column_name = 'updated'
        and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
        and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    order by t.table_schema;
```

[Source: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/amazon-redshift/find-tables-with-specific-column-name]

Answer (score 1):

you can select the most recent date from each table and union together (and put in a view if you like).

Select * from (select top 1 'test', updated from test order by updated desc)
union all
Select * from (select top 1 'big_table', updated from big_table order by updated desc);

You can have a long list of "union all"s up to some limit.  This hard codes the tables into the view - I assume this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for this. This is what I was thinking I might have to do. I was hoping to do something a bit more dyncamic using code such as this to get all the tables and schemas that have the column. (Added code to original post as cant format it here in comments)

Comment: By being "dynamic"  the SQL you will want to issue will change as tables in the database change.  This brings you data request into a more procedural realm.  I expect this can be done with a python UDF but this isn't my forte.  If I had this problem I would look outside of Redshift to the AWS cloud to run the procedural aspect - namely Lambda.  The Lambda function can find the table with the column and loop through this list finding the latest date.  It can store this back in a table if you like.  Just have Lambda use a single transaction to ensure data consistency.